computing elevation angle of a object on a circular fisheye image
I'd like to calculate the elevation angle of an object at any given coordinates (x,y) of the image that has been taken with a circular fisheye lens (185° of fov). By elevation angle, I mean the angle between the horizontal line passing through the camera and the line passing through the camera and the object in a 3D space (the alpha angle in the schema down there).
schema
I was thinking about using the orthographic mapping function r = f x sin(theta) as it is written on the wikipidia page of fisheye lenses, but I am not sure what to do exactly.
Anybody could help me please ?

The angle $\theta$ in a mapping function such as the five examples on the Wikipedia page represents the angle measured from the optical axis. Given $x$ and $y$ coordinates on the photographic plate with respect to the centre of the picture, the distance to the centre is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$
From your picture I infer that the camera is pointed directly upwards at the zenith, so "horizontal" means perpendicular to the optical axis of the lens. This implies that the elevation $\eta$ is the complementary angle $90°-\theta$ and "elevation" refers to the angular distance between the object and the horizon.
The rest depends on the design of the lens, which determines the mapping function. Working from your example $r=f\sin\theta$ (where $f$ is the known focal length) you can solve this for $\theta$ as
$$\eta=90°-\theta=90°-\hbox{Arcsin}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/f)=\hbox{Arccos}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/f).$$
If you do not know the focal length you can measure it (for this particular mapping function) as the radius of the image disk.
A lens like this can never have more than $180°$ field of view (as noted in Wikipedia). If your lens has $185°$ then it must have a different mapping function.

It's a miracle that you understood my question and it's even a bigger one that you answered to it perfectly. Thanks a lot !
